# Display System Time on PDF Report R

Tags: r, pdf

I'm trying to write a title page for an R report to a pdf. (Yes; I'm sure sweave, markdown, and probably other things would make it look nicer, but I'd like to work with pdf()).

The Sys.time command seems to overwrite any additional text I place. Am I missing something here?

```
function example(dataframe1,dataframe2){
      pdf("C:/Desktop/sample.pdf", 7, 5)

      plot(0:10, type = "n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
      text(5, 8, "Comparison Report of:")
      text(5, 7, deparse(substitute(dataframe1)))
      text(5, 6, " & ")
      text(5, 5, deparse(substitute(dataframe2)))
      text(5, 4, paste(c("Created ",Sys.time()),compress=''))

      dev.off()
}
```

Comment: `as.character(Sys.time()))`

Comment: Problem comes from your `c()` in `paste` it seems. You can use `text(5, 4, paste("Created", Sys.time(),compress=''))`

Comment: Thanks for this!!!